# Bone Limit Rotation constraint not fully working

Tags: rigging, constraints

So I'm using a Damped Track constraint and over that a Limit Rotation constraint as I only want the bone to rotate in X axis. This is the only setup I get it "working" but it has one tiny mistake, it rotates it a little bit to one of the sides, when it's not supposed to.

[image]

Even weirder is that if I take off the Limit Rotation constraint and I make it so the bone naturally only rotates on the axis I want then it looks fine (but I need the Limit constraint).

[image]

I would really appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Note: if I change the Convert option to anything else other than Local (or Local with Parent) then it goes all over the place.

--- EDIT ---

After doing Locked Track as constraint instead of Damped Track and Limit Rotation the rotation still happens, even when I'm not moving the tracked bone in X:

[image]

Comment: Its x axis rotation isn't necessarily what you think it is, because transforms are matrices that are converted to Eulers for evaluating constraints, and there isn't a 1:1 correspondence between Eulers and actual orientations (XYZ euler 180/0/0 == XYZ euler 0/180/180.)  For people that don't know their 3D math inside and out, which is almost everybody, Euler angles are alluring but deadly sirens.  If you want it to be limited to a single axis of rotation, use a Locked Track constraint instead.

Comment: @Nathan thanks, I hadn't seen that constraint and it seems to work fine like those other two but that tiny rotation still happens o,O I'll add the screenshot to the main post.

Comment: "Tiny rotation"-- don't give it a limit rotation constraint.  Only use the locked track constraint.

Comment: If that's what you have (can't see with cropped screenshot), then we need to see bone axes, and probably a file would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I found this video on YouTube. You can watch this video.

https://youtu.be/y6ECmeANUSw

Comment: Hello and welcome the site! Please explain the important bits of the video that answer the question asked in your answer. That way your answer will still be useful even if the video is removed. The link to the video should only be additional information, not the main part of your answer.